# Trying to Export Tables to CSVs from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I ran the following script to try to get all tables in my DB exported (trying to backup the data in CSVs).

```
SELECT 'sqlcmd -S . -d '+DB_NAME()+' -E -s, -W -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT * FROM '+table_schema+'.'+TABLE_name+'" > "C:\Temp\'+Table_Name+'.csv"' 
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
```

I saved the results as a batch file and ran the batch file as Administrator. 
 That runs without an error, but I get no data exported.  All it does is create blank CSV files.

I ran this as well: `'EXEC sp_configure 'remote access',1 reconfigure'`.

Still, nothing is exported. CSVs are created, but no data is exported...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not just use database backups?

Comment: LOL!!  I wish I could sir.  Where I work there is A LOT of politics and the people that maintain this database for us won't do that.  People don't help people unless they work in the same department.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using R to do the task...

```
library("RODBC")
conn <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=Server_Name;DB_Name;trusted_connection=true')


data <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.TBL#1")    
write.csv(data,file=paste("C:/Users/TBL#1.csv",sep=""),row.names=FALSE)
data <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.TBL#2")    
write.csv(data,file=paste("C:/Users/TBL#2.csv",sep=""),row.names=FALSE)
```

Gotta love the IT teams in corporate America...especially when they lock down your system so tight, you need to come up with all kinds of weird hacks just so you can do the job that you were hired to do...

Is there a word for negative synergy?